# How can emacs preview java jmod file like jar file from dired?

Tags: dired, java, compression

They are both zip file actually. I can preview jar file directly from dired, but not for jmod files.

I tried

1. adding `jmod` to `dired-compress-file-suffixes`, not working.

```lisp
(add-to-list 'dired-compress-file-suffixes '("\\.jmod\\'" "" "unzip -o -d %o %i"))
```

by the way, `jar` is not in `dired-compress-file-suffixes` too.

2. tried `jka-compr-compression-info-list`, got error message `File mode specification error: (error Buffer format not recognized)`

```lisp
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.jmod\\'" . archive-mode))
(add-to-list 'jka-compr-compression-info-list
             ["\\.jmod\\'"
              nil
              nil
              nil
              nil
              "unzip"
              ("-q" "-c")
              nil
              nil
              "JM"
              ])
```

Comment: Also asked [at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77328174/1319821).